# Where to load packages when sourcing an R script

Tags: r

I have two R scripts. scriptB is called in scriptA via source("scriptB.R")

both scriptA and scriptB load the same `library(x)` where x is `knitr` or `stringr` or a few other packages

However, because scriptB calls `library(x)` for example, it seems scriptA is forced to unload its `library(x)` and then load up the scriptB `library(x)`. This leads to the following error:

```
Error in unloadNamespace(package) : 
  namespace 'x' is imported by 'y' so cannot be unloaded
Error in library(x) : Package 'x' version n.nn cannot be unloaded
```

I don't actually call unloadNamespace in the source script so I'm not sure why this is happening? How can I prevent the unload. Should I just use `require()` in scriptA so it can fail gracefully?

So my questions are:

1. Is sourcing the R script the best way to include objects from the R script or is there a friendlier way
2. How do I avoid the script from trying to unload package x?

Comment: If you are already using `library(x)` in script A you don't need to `library(x)` in script B then

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference whether you call `library(x)` once or multiple times. Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

OK I sorted it. The problem I think was I was using old versions of stringr in scriptA or B so I updated the package and now it runs fine. I suppose R unloads the same library if there is a versioning difference and probably prefers the library that is called last. That's my only explanation.

I remain a little confused however as I didn't specify a version of the library when loading it and I though rstudio only keeps one version of a package.